# Simulink and memory leaks

Tags: matlab, memory-leaks, simulink

I suspect there is a memory leak in Simulink. I'm running MATLAB 2012b on Mac OS X v10.8.2. I ran 200 simulations involving an invocation to a Simulink model (using the command `sim`) while timing each invocation. I noticed that the first one was around 200s and the execution time kept increasing simulation after simulation until it reached 154s. The simulations were of equal complexity, so the difference in execution time cannot be justified. I suspect that there is some sort of memory leak. Note that the Simulink model doesn't involve any calls to MEX files.

Comment: The first simulation always carries some overhead and will take longer. Subsequent run should be faster. Can't really comment about the memory leak, it might model-specific.

Comment: @am304 The first simulation completed in 60s, the second in 61s, and the execution time kept increasing. This is why I suspect some memory leak. The Simulink model I'm using is very standard: It is a closed-loop dynamical system, I'm using the ODE23s numerical solver, and there are no MEX file invocations.

Comment: Is the workspace clean when a new simulation starts? Maybe you are dynamically concatenating some vectors, which grow a lot from one simulation to another (like data that you use later for plotting).

Comment: I noticed the same thing in one of my project where I call the `sim` command in a `for` loop with different simulation parameters. I still have not found the source of the problem.

Comment: Why would increased run-time be indicative of a memory leak? When memory gets scarce, I would first expect more swapping, which would induce much longer delays than a few seconds, later Matlab would tell you that it is out of memory, and in a severe case Matlab might crash simply crash.

Comment: Try profiling to see where the extra time is spent. Rethink your algorithms to ascertain whether they really are of equal complexity.

Comment: Have you watched your memory during this time? 200sims that take a minute each should give you plenty of data to figure out if you have  a mem leak.